# Redesigning and removing Task.Delay() from my C# function

Tags: c#, async-await

I have my below code which runs when `Task.Delay(500000)` but when my `Task.Delay(5000)` it does not give me any result as the time duration is very less to execute the output expected. I am looking for a way to redesign code where I can handle this without `Task.Delay()` as my response time may vary for each execution. How should I do it?

Note: Modified the code with the method suggested in answer by Roald. Earlier query on Task.Delay() cant be handled asynchronously for Change Feed. The other way around will be to use Pull model instead of Push Model

```cs
    using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
    using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ChangeFeedProcessor;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Channels;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
    namespace ConsoleApp1
    {
        public class ChangeFeedProcessorOptions
        {
            public int BufferCapacity { get; set; }
            public string ProcessorName { get; set; }
            public Container LeaseContainer { get; set; }
            public string InstanceName { get; set; }
            public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
        }
        
        class Program
        {
    
            
    
            static async Task Main()
            {
                var client = new CosmosClient("AccountEndpoint = https://test.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=oaEOA==;");
    
                var database = client.GetDatabase("testDatabase");
                var container = database.GetContainer("testContainer");
    
                var options = new ChangeFeedProcessorOptions
                {
                    BufferCapacity = 10,
                    InstanceName = "ChangeFeedInstanceName",
                    LeaseContainer = database.GetContainer("leases"),
                    ProcessorName = "ChangeFeedProcessorName",
                    StartTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).ToUniversalTime()
                };
    
                var count = 0;
                await foreach (var doc in container.GetChangeFeed<document>(options))
                {
                    Console.Write(doc, b: true);
    
                    count++;
    
                    if (count == 6)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }     
    
    
            
    
        public static async IAsyncEnumerable<document> GetChangeFeed<document>(this Container self, ChangeFeedProcessorOptions options, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<document>(new BoundedChannelOptions(options.BufferCapacity)
            {
                FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait,
                SingleReader = true,
                SingleWriter = true
            });
    
            var processor = self
                .GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder<document>(options.ProcessorName, async (items, cancellation) =>
                {
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(item, cancellation);
                    }
                })
                .WithLeaseContainer(options.LeaseContainer)
                .WithInstanceName(options.InstanceName)
                .WithStartTime(options.StartTime)
                .Build();
    
            await processor.StartAsync();
            try
            {
                await foreach (var item in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))
                {
                    yield return item;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                await processor.StopAsync();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is `ProcessChanges` what takes all of the time? Perhaps you could do something with `TaskCompletionSource` or a `SempahoreSlim`?

Comment: The line "await cfp.StartAsync();" should block until all the data is received (the fulll response) and the delay is not required.  If the await was removed then you would need the delay.

Comment: ProcessChanges do take the time, its a delegate which handles the changes. can you please elaborate on TaskCompletionSource

Comment: It doesnot work with Task.Delay() removed

Comment: What's the point of using `Task.Run` only to *block* waiting for a result? `Task.Delay()` shouldn't be needed anyway. Whatever `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` do, there shouldn't be any need for a delay inside an already blocked call. One would have to guess what's wrong as the relevant code is missing

Comment: @AnkitKumar you may or may not need a TaskCompletionSource. You shouldn't need that Task.Delay at all. Something's wrong with the `StartAsync` and `StopAsync` methods but we can't guess what

Comment: We are calling ProcessChanges() where we have WriteObject which is not supported with async method. What do you recommend, what else should I provide here

Comment: I am actually using this code from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor#implementing-the-change-feed-processor

Comment: A change feed is like an infinite stream and has no meaningful notion of 'completing' and therefore no way to wait for it. Can you clarify a bit what you are actually trying to do? for example are you trying to read until you see a particular record, a certain number of records or something else?

Comment: I am reading this from a Powershell cmdlet, and I want to  see all the documents where changes occurred after a certain time defined in my function

Comment: but let say I would like to put a limit on no of records returned? What should be the approach

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the most flexible way is to first turn the change feed into an IAsyncEnumerable so that then you can just use linq or some straight forward imperative code to process it.

You can get the IAsyncEnumerable using this extension method

**SDK version <= 3.15.0**

```
public record ChangeFeedProcessorOptions
{
    public int BufferCapacity { get; init; }
    public string ProcessorName { get; init; }
    public Container LeaseContainer { get; init; }
    public string InstanceName { get; init; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; init; }
}

public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetChangeFeed<T>(this Container self, ChangeFeedProcessorOptions options, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<T>(new BoundedChannelOptions(options.BufferCapacity)
    {
        FullMode = BoundedChannelFullMode.Wait,
        SingleReader = true,
        SingleWriter = true
    });

    var processor = self
        .GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder<T>(options.ProcessorName, async (items, cancellation) =>
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                await channel.Writer.WriteAsync(item, cancellation);
            }
        })
        .WithLeaseContainer(options.LeaseContainer)
        .WithInstanceName(options.InstanceName)
        .WithStartTime(options.StartTime)
        .Build();

    await processor.StartAsync();
    try
    {
        await foreach (var item in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync(cancellationToken))
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        await processor.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

**SDK version > 3.15.0**

```
public record ChangeFeedProcessorOptions
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; init; }
    public TimeSpan PollInterval { get; init; }
}

public static async IAsyncEnumerable<T> GetChangeFeed<T>(this Container self, ChangeFeedProcessorOptions options, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var iterator = self.GetChangeFeedIterator<T>(ChangeFeedStartFrom.Time(options.StartTime));

    while (iterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        FeedResponse<T> items;

        try
        {
            items = await iterator.ReadNextAsync(cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (CosmosException ex) when (ex.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotModified)
        {
            // No changes
            await Task.Delay(options.PollInterval, cancellationToken);
            continue;
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var client = new CosmosClient("AccountEndpoint = https://test.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=oaEOA==;");

    var database = client.GetDatabase("testDatabase");
    var container = database.GetContainer("testContainer");

    var options = new ChangeFeedProcessorOptions
    {
        BufferCapacity = 10,
        InstanceName = ChangeFeedInstanceName,
        LeaseContainer = database.GetContainer("leases"),
        ProcessorName = ChangeFeedProcessorName,
        StartTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(MaxAge).ToUniversalTime()
    };
    
    var count = 0;
    await foreach (var doc in container.GetChangeFeed<Recording>(options))
    {
        WriteObject(doc, b: true);
        
        count++;
        
        if (count == 6)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

or even better if you add [`System.Linq.Async`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/)

```
await foreach (var doc in container.GetChangeFeed<Recording>(options).Take(6))
{
    WriteObject(doc, b: true);
}
```

For a different implementation you can also take a look [here](https://www.tpeczek.com/2020/01/exposing-cosmos-db-change-feed-from.html), it uses two semaphores instead of a Channel to achieve the same result.

#### Async code in powershell cmdlets

The issues you are having are due to the fact that in a cmdlet calls to `WriteObject`, `WriteVerbose`, `WriteWarning`, etc are required to come from the main thread.
To solve this you need to run a message pump in `ProcessRecord` and use it to post back to the main thread when you need to call any of those methods, exactly what you would have to do in WinForm or WPF using the Dispatcher.
A library that takes care of this is [PowerShellAsync](https://github.com/ttrider/PowerShellAsync)

using the library your code would become

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "ChangedRecording")]
[OutputType(typeof(Recording))]
public class SyncRecording : AsyncCmdlet
{
    // ...
    
    protected override async Task ProcessRecordAsync()
    {
        var container = ...;
        await foreach (var doc in container.GetChangeFeed<Recording>(options).Take(6))
        {
            WriteObject(doc, b: true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Roald, after days of trying I am finally moving to your approach.. the code you suggested above has few errors like public record ChangeFeedProcessorOptions what assembly refers record?

Comment: @AnkitKumar records and init-only properties are c# 9 features, you can read about them here https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/c-9-0-on-the-record/ , if you can't use c#9 just replace 'record' with 'class' and 'init' with 'set'.

Comment: @AnkitKumar yes I tested it.. you need to read those error messages! compiling your code it says "[CS1106] Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class". GetChangeFeed is an extension method and therefore must be declared in a static class, but you copied it into Program which is not static.
more info in extension methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: left with one error now container.GetChangeFeedBuilder<document>(options)) , It says container do not contain definition for GetChangeFeedBuilder. Which packages are you using

Comment: yes thats right GetChangeFeedProcessorBuilder is available but it gives an error as doesnot get definition for GetAsyncEnumerator. If you tested the code, how you got the GetChangedFeedBuilder??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225830/discussion-between-roald-and-ankit-kumar).